# How to reuse a CDI/Weld request scoped bean in an application context with little changes?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, superclass, reusability, weld

Suppose that I have a `@RequestScoped` bean that have 5 other `@RequestScoped` beans injected into it.

Suppose that I need to reuse this bean in an application scoped context where no request is present. I had to extend all beans and add `@ApplicationScoped` annotation on them. Also I had to create getters/setters for fields and use these getters/setters for accessing fields so that their access may be overridden in subclass.

Is it the correct way of doing this? Is there any simpler way of reusing a request scoped bean in an application scoped context?

Comment: Instead of having to extend all beans and `@Override` their methods, you could provide an interface, as well as an abstract class that would contain the common behavior, for each one of them. Then, you could have two implementations, one for the `@RequestScoped` and another for the `@ApplicationScoped` that you could inject directly or using a `Producer`.

Comment: @aribeiro: why not create this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could potentially use an ugly hack through "producer methods". The problem seems to be, you have some *RequestScope* bean, and you want to move it to *ApplicationScope*.

You could do this:

```java
@Produces @ApplicationScope
public SomeInterface getSomeBean(@New SomeBean bean) {
    return bean;
}
```

With this you can "promote" a bean to another scope. Notice that `@ApplicationScope` annotation which promotes it, and notice the `@New` annotation on the method, which basically says CDI to ignore the normal bean scope and just make a new one.

The remaining problem is the request scope dependencies `bean` still has. You can solve this by injecting them all with `@New` into the method. Something like:

```java
@Produces @ApplicationScope
public SomeInterface getSomeBean(
        @New SomeDependency1 dep1,
        @New SomeDependency2 dep2,
        ...) {
    return new SomeBean(dep1, dep2, ...);
}
```

So basically manually create the bean with "promoted" dependencies.

Note: you probably have to *qualify* one or both beans, so you can decide whether you want the request or application scoped one at an injection point.